# memberOf returns different values for the same user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, memberof

Using the same LDAP search query in our Java app, we get different values for memberOf while executing the java app for the same user.

The LDAP configuration to Active Directory is as below,

hostname - sscad.gcs.com
User DN - cn=pavin,CN=Users,DC=gcs,DC=com
Password - Password1kjlkj
Use SSL - true

Looks like the 636 port is being used for this config. Why does AD return different results?

Comment: You would need to provide some more information (Not your passwords) and some code.

Comment: You would need to provide the expected and actual results, for a start.